# iOS draw circle on navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation bar on the top of my screen. Is there a way to draw a small green circle? I'd like to be able to enable/disable it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by enable/disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CGContext to draw a circle at a specified spot

Watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aMb8xEx660 , Demo starts at minute 53

Demo Source: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Happiness_0.zip

Lecture PDF: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%205.pdf

Sorry for not answering the option to enable/disable it. I don't really know how to do that.

Maybe you can use a view which you put that circle on, and then you can load/unload it whenever you want :)